# How to enable "source editor" option in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CK Editor 5 (Classic Build). But I am not able to see the source editor option.

Answer (score 4):

The best way I found is to build from their online builder.
[You can build online from here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the documentation here. It is quite clearly explained
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/source-editing.html#installation